# Android : first activity launched

Tags: android, user-interface

A strange behavior I'm tearing my eyes on since early this afternoon, I'm givin up understanding but perhaps someone has an idea (yeah, I'm a beginner, some PROBABLY has an idea ^^).

Situation :

MainActivity.java (first one to be called, only one of interest here)

```
    public ExpandableListView listClubs;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listClubs = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expLstMainClubs);
    AppGlobal.CreateDistricts() ;

    ELVAdapterDistrictsClubs adapter = new ELVAdapterDistrictsClubs(this);      
    listClubs.setAdapter(adapter);  
    }
```

it's the only code in the class. Basically, I'm filling an ExpandableList with an adapter that relies on what's created in the CreateDistricts() method (creates business objects, Districts containing Clubs containing Members, Events, etc.).

Basically (again ^^), everything runs fine, on first start the ExpList works as expected, as well as the rest of the app. If I hit the back button from the MainActivity, however, and rerun the app, a "strange" (to me at least) behavior occurs :

The ExpList is loaded twice in a row - first one with the data, works fine, and just below a duplicate (with the same 2 Groups, i.e. here the only two Districts in my sample data), which doesn't work at all (if you try to expand it, it crashes the app).

Frankly, I'm lost - I've tried some things on the various on[Pause/Stop/Destroy/Start/Resume] etc. to no avail (therefore, there is yet nothing done on this side, no override, as it seems not to bring anything good).

As the onCreate will after the onDestroy load the bundle, it should load the ExpList as it were, and in this case there might be a conflict between the "old" groups/children and the actual ones (currently, data is simulated, but will afterward come from a remote data source), and I haven't decided yet what the best "save" behavior is, i.e. if I should find a way to obliterate the ExpList onDestroy in order to be sure it's 100% recreated anew (and how does one do that ?) and start from scratch, or if I could use the ExpList as is, while updating it's content, in order not to lose the previous selection. It may be irrelevant to complicate matters in order to do that, the first list being not so big and quite quickly used to reach the second activity...

Anyway, I suspect it comes from around that part, the bundle load after destroy and rerunning, does it reload the ExpList as is and then I add things instead of first deleting ? What I found confusing is that the next activity (reached simply by clicking one of the items of the ExpList) displays a similar ExpList (filled with Months and Events per Month for the selected Club), and doesn't present the same strange behavior after a destroy... and both have an almost identical ExpList declaration in their original xml layout so... well, perhaps tomorrow morning I'll see the light, but if anyone has an idea, feel free :D

The more I write, the more I think I should first clear the ExpList but... I don't see how exactly. I've tried

```
listClubs.removeViewsInLayout(0, listClubs.getCount()) ;
```

but it just doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code for `AppGlobal.CreateDistricts()`, what it's doing is affecting this behavior I suspect.

Comment: @Steven : exactly, how to lose hours on the false side of the problem. what I forgot was to NOT recreate the content of the ArrayList in CreateDistricts() .... talk about being dumb ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing related to Android behavior - I was recreating *everytime* the whole set of BO behind if the base ArrayList of Districts was not null... instead of simply getting out of the method, but it raises another question - how was the state of this ArrayList, which is declared in a subclass of Application serving as Application in my manifest ? I'll have to make some tests about that...